# I cant get the results

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to get the values from `app.config` but I get an error. I tried another little application and it turns right.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++ )
    {
        this.comboBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString("D2"));
        this.comboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString("D2"));
    }

    string minutos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["minutos"];
    string segundos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["segundos"];

    //label3.Text = minutos;


    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 30;
    this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 59;
}
```

This is the error

https://ibb.co/LSCPsxN "tooltip"

[image]

Comment: _it gives me an error_ is not a good description of your problem. If you have an error message then post that error message instead

Comment: So what's the error (if any), where is it thrown?

Comment: this is the error   https://ibb.co/LSCPsxN

Comment: By the way, if those combos should contain a list of minutes then you are adding one too much. Minutes go from 00 to 59

Comment: no, it should look like this         string minutos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["minutos"];
            string segundos = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["segundos"];

            //label3.Text = minutos;


            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(minutos);
            this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(segundos);

Comment: @devilonline Sorry, what's that in English? Something about system configuration?

Comment: Thank you. by the way do you know what I'm doing wrong please? Thank you

Comment: No, we don't know what you're doing wrong. We need the error text in English, at least as a start.

Comment: Please also post your app.config

Comment: the exception indicates there is a timer issue in the Form Load method.  Usually errors like this are race conditions where the timer is firing before every thing in the form is constructed and loaded.  How many items are loaded in the combobox.  I suspect the combobox  doesn't have 59 items so you are indexing the combobox outside the range.  But that doesn't account for the exception indicating a timer issue.

Comment: this is my code. and this is my app.config https://anotepad.com/notes/rdft9tx  https://ibb.co/xDpT7Y2

Comment: @jdweng The OP named their project `timer`, but that doesn't mean it has to do with a `Timer`

Comment: Please review [ask].  You need to post _all_ the relevant code for recreating the problem _within the question_ as a [mcve].

Comment: Please post the full exception message, preferably translated to English. The screenshot you've shown is only showing the bottom part of the message.

Answer (score 1):

It appears (from [this link](https://ibb.co/xDpT7Y2) hidden in the comments) that you've added your settings directly to the `<configuration>` node, rather than inside an `<appSettings>` node.

Try modifying your config by adding an `appSettings` node and then placing your settings inside it, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>         
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1"/>
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="minutos" value="30"/>
        <add key="segundos" value="59"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```